# How do I update emacs on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, emacs, dnf

I currently have emacs 24.5 installed and would like to update to 25.1. when I type `dnf update emacs` I get

```
Last metadata expiration check: 1:29:14 ago on Thu Mar 30 09:42:12 2017.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

How do I update something when dnf tells me there's nothing to do?

Comment: OK, thanks — which version of Fedora?

Comment: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/25/html/System_Administrators_Guide/ch-DNF.html

You gotta see what's available in the repositories; irrespective of the distribution, that's how it works (unless we're talking 3rd party repos, etc.)

Comment: @ILMostro_7 what I'm curious about is that Emacs 25 *is* available in the Fedora repos, at least for 24 and 25.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what Fedora version are you using, but latest Fedora 25 has emacs 25.1 in repository, as you can notice in the list of updates:

https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/?packages=emacs

It is available also in Fedora 24 as visible in the above list so you are probably using something older and therefore you should update your whole system, because Fedora 23 and older versions are [EOL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/End_of_life)

Comment: Ah it seems I am still running Fedora 23. I guess I will consider updating everything, but I am hesitant since I have never done this. Out of curiosity, what happens if I choose to do that? Emacs will automatically get updated?

Comment: There is not much to worry about. Yes, your emacs will get updated by doing this.

Comment: We've (I work on Fedora) put a lot of effort into making upgrades quick and seamless in the last few releases. Follow the [instructions here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF_system_upgrade). (Of course, something can always go wrong — make a backup first! — but for most people it's simply a matter of following the steps, going for a cup of coffee, and coming back to an upgraded system.)

Comment: OK then, here goes!

Comment: @mattdm it seems like I will first have to update to version 24, and then to 25? I can't go straight from 23 to 25?

Comment: Skipping one release should work; this is a scenario we test, and I know of no particular reason F23→F25 would be problematic.

Comment: How do I do that then? Do I specify a version in `dnf install fedora-upgrade`?

Comment: @theQman you specify the target release in the step 4.: `sudo dnf system-upgrade download --refresh --releasever=25`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a version

```
dnf install emacs-25.1-3
```

As an example on Fedora25.

If there are dependency issues, try one of the following:

```
dnf check-update; dnf upgrade --best
```

Or, if you'd like, you can tell it to "allow erasing" other packages.  This is destructive, obviously.

```
dnf upgrade --allowerasing
```

Finally, you also have an option to upgrade to a specific version; though, this appears to be an obsolete option.

```
dnf upgrade-to
```

From the man-pages:

> dnf [options] repository-packages  upgrade-to
>   ...
>       Update packages to the specified versions that are available in the repository. Upgrade-to is deprecated alias for the upgrade
>   subcommand.

If you notice, you used the `update` option, rather than `upgrade` in your initial command.

Please take a look at the [Fedora Admin Guide: Software Management](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/25/html/System_Administrators_Guide/ch-DNF.html) as well as the [DNF Documentation](http://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).